# is realtec RTL8832AU supported on raspberry debian bullseye

Tags: wifi, usb

anyone got the driver installed for realtec RTL8832AU supported on raspberry debian bullseye

Comment: you may want to read [this](https://github.com/morrownr/USB-WiFi/blob/main/home/USB_WiFi_Adapter_out-of-kernel_drivers_for_Linux.md#chipset---rtl8832au--rtl8852au---ax1800---usb-3) - apparently (as of April 2022) the RTL8832AU drivers in Linux are hot garbage

Comment: thx good to know